# ¿Cómo se haría un toString de una matriz de forma recursiva en java?

Tags: java, recursión

```
//n = número de filas y //m = número de columnas

  public String toString(double [][] a, int n, int m){

}
```

El punto es hacer que imprima cada elemento preferentemente en forma de matriz, pero de forma recursiva, es decir sin algún ciclo como un for.

Comment: La forma como lo presentas, parece que se trata de un ejercicio escolar. Si es el caso, sería apropiado que lo intentes por tu cuenta primero.

Comment: Sólo con esos parametros? o se pueden recibir más parámetros?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que logro entender es que es un Tema escolar en el cual se toca el tema de recursividad empleando una matriz de n dimensiones, bueno primero es entender como funciona la recursividad en lenguajes de programación:

**Recursividad** :
Es una técnica utilizada en programación que nos permite que un bloque de instrucciones se ejecute un cierto número de veces (el que nosotros determinemos).

Un ejemplo simple de llamada recursiva:

```
void cuentaRegresiva () {
      cuentaRegresiva();
}
```

Este método no hace  prácticamente nada, solo se llama a si mismo. Si se ejecuta este código así tal cual se obtendrá un StackOverFlow Error.

Por ejemplo para  hacer una cuenta regresiva sin utilidad Recursividad, tendríamos que emplea un loop for por ejemplo, algo así:

```
for( int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

Ahora si queremos emplear la técnica recursiva tendremos que pasar como parámetro un número. Además de imprimir el número, la función se llama a si misma con el numero actual restando uno.

```
void cuentaRegresiva(int numero) {
      System.out.println(numero);
      cuentaRegresiva(numero - 1);
}
```

Por ejemplo llamamos a la función con un 10. Imprimimos el 10 y llamamos a la función con un 9. Imprimimos el 9 y llamamos a la función con un 8. Así hasta el fin de los días. Digo hasta el fin de los días porque  va a saltar error si se ejecuta esto así directamente:

```
public class Recursividad {

    static void cuentaRegresiva(int numero) {
        System.out.println(numero);
        cuentaRegresiva(numero - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cuentaRegresiva(10);
    }   
}
```

Qué problema tiene este código?, estamos haciendo llamada al mismo método de manera "infinita" ya que no existe una condicional que evite que siga la ejecución cuando el numero llegue a cero. Para solucionar esto, las llamadas recursivas se apoyan de una estructura condicional (if) o comúnmente llamado un "ancla".

```
void cuentaRegresiva(int numero) {
      System.out.println(numero);
      if(numero > 0) {
            cuentaRegresiva(numero - 1);
      }
}
```

De esta forma, la función recursiva se llamara a si misma si y solo si numero es mayor a cero.

Y básicamente así funciona una técnica recursiva.

Atendiendo a tu pregunta ahora que ya leíste un poco de recursividad, podrás entender el método que puede imprimir una matriz haciendo llamadas recursivas:

```
  package com.stack.over.flow.ejemplos;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrizRecursiva {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        int filas;
        int columnas;

        Matrixita mi_matriz = new Matrixita();
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("digite el numero de filas  ");
        filas = leer.nextInt();

        System.out.println("digite el numero de columnas ");
        columnas = leer.nextInt();

        int[][] matriz = mi_matriz.llenar_matriz(0, 0, filas, columnas);

        System.out.println("--------------- matriz-----------------");
        mi_matriz.mostrar_matriz(0, 0, filas, columnas);

    }
}

class Matrixita {
    private int[][] matriz = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, {0, 0, 0 } };

    int sw = 0;
    int sw1 = 0;

    public int[][] llenar_matriz(int i, int j, int filas, int columnas) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (sw == 0) {
            if (i < filas) {

                if (j < columnas) {

                    System.out.println("digite numero de posicion " + " " + i
                            + " " + j);
                    matriz[i][j] = teclado.nextInt(); 

                    llenar_matriz(i, j + 1, filas, columnas);

                }

                if (j == columnas) {

                    llenar_matriz(i + 1, 0, filas, columnas);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("matriz llenada satisfactoriamente");
                sw = 1;
            }
        }
        return this.matriz;

    }

    public void mostrar_matriz(int i, int j, int filas, int columnas) {

        if (sw1 == 0) {
            if (i < filas) {

                if (j < columnas) {
                    System.out.println("- " + i + " " + j);
                    System.out.println(matriz[i][j]);
                    mostrar_matriz(i, j + 1, filas, columnas);
                }

                if (j == columnas) {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
                    mostrar_matriz(i + 1, 0, filas, columnas);

                }
            } else {
                sw1 = 1;
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

El código recibe los indices iniciales de la matrix así como el número de filas y columnas. Se recorre la matriz recursivamente mostrando sus valores con un System.out.println("- " + i + " " + j);

Si queda alguna duda sobre este tema, lo mejor será investigar y hacer ejercicios para dominar el tema.

Comment: Voiser,  a su función recursiva hace falta pasar la matriz como parametro

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo como quieren imprimir los elementos del arreglo sin usar ciclos, es antinatural e ineficiente,

Comment: @ArieCwHat no es tan difícil haciendo uso de las bondades de  java y en especial de la clase `Arrays`.

Comment: solo intenta imprimir {{ 1,2,3,4,5 }, { 7, 8, 9, 10}} usando recursión... definitivamente si es una tarea.... discutiría con el profe... recursivamente. :(

Comment: Si, lo sé, para este ejemplo agrego código completo, es una forma de hacer pero desde luego se adapta a otras implementaciones dependerá que busca exactamente el compañero :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas.

Has intentado deepToString de la clase Arrays?.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arreglo));
```

Esto imprime el formato:

```
[[99, 151], [30, 5]]
```

Puedes ver la documentacion de [Arrays.deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void imprimir(double[][] d, int x, int y){
    if (y < d.length && x < d[0].length){
        System.out.print(String.format("%+e ",d[y][x]));
        imprimir(d,++x,y);
    } else if (y < d.length-1 && x == d[0].length){
        System.out.println();
        imprimir(d, 0, ++y);
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] d = {{3,5,2,6,8},{9,4,1,7,1},{3,3,3,3,3},{4,2,6,4,5}};
    imprimir(d,0,0);
}
```

Consola:

```
+3,000000e+00 +5,000000e+00 +2,000000e+00 +6,000000e+00 +8,000000e+00 
+9,000000e+00 +4,000000e+00 +1,000000e+00 +7,000000e+00 +1,000000e+00 
+3,000000e+00 +3,000000e+00 +3,000000e+00 +3,000000e+00 +3,000000e+00 
+4,000000e+00 +2,000000e+00 +6,000000e+00 +4,000000e+00 +5,000000e+00
```

La lógica de la recursividad esta en los primeros condiciónes donde el método llama a si mismo con valores modificados. Para no resolver la recursividad de atras, se imprime primero y luego se llama al método de nuevo.